# Estimating a linear state space model of a dataset using n4sid and testing it

Tags: matlab, testing, dataset, system, identification

In the system identification toolbox how may I have a train and test set?
I mean, when using n4sid function, for example, I can give one output data y and estimate a linear state space model corresponding that data. But, what if I want to give a set of 100 signals and estimate only one model for this data? and then test it for, say, 50 other signals?

Any help is appreciated,
Atena